# How do I get the code to exit at 4 and go back to initial "Enter an ID"? I think everything else is fine (may be wrong)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

The question is this:

Simulate an ATM machine.

Create ten accounts in an array with id 0, 1, . . . , 9, and initial balance $100. The system prompts the user to enter an id. If the ID is entered incorrectly, ask the user to enter a correct id. Once an ID is accepted, the main menu is displayed as shown in the sample run. You can enter a choice 1 for viewing the current balance, 2 for withdrawing money, 3 for depositing money, and 4 for exiting the main menu. Once you exit, the system will prompt for an id again. Thus, once the system starts, it will not stop.

My code is this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Account9_07 test = new Account9_07();
    test.setBalance(100.00);

    int [] account = new int [9];

    for( ; ;) {
        System.out.print("Enter an ID # (0-9): ");
        int IDinput = input.nextInt();

        if( IDinput <10 && IDinput > 0)
            break;

        System.out.println("The ID entered is incorrect. Please enter the correct ID  \n");
    }
    for( ; ; ) {
        System.out.println("\n Main Menu " + "\n 1: check balance " + " \n 2: withdraw" + "\n 3: deposit" + "\n 4: exit" );
        System.out.print(" Enter a choice: ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        if(choice == 1) {
            System.out.print("\n The balance is " + test.getBalance());
        }

        else if(choice == 2) {
            System.out.print("How much would you like to withdraw: ");
            double withdraw = input.nextDouble();
            test.withdraw(withdraw);
        }

        else if(choice == 3) {
            System.out.print("How much would you like to deposit: ");
            double deposit = input.nextDouble();
            test.deposit(deposit);
        }
        if( choice == 4)
            break;
    }
    //4 is not looping back to enter an ID
}
```

Comment: change your `for`s statement by `while` conditionals

Comment: @JorgeCampos:  And that would change...what?  A for loop written like that is equivalent to `while(true)`.

Comment: @Jay So you want to loop back to the first for loop from the second for loop if the user enters 4, right?

Comment: Yes, if user hits 4 it will return to “Enter an ID”

Comment: You should place both loops in one outer while loop, so you can go from the second loop to the first loop (I'll post an answer on this)

Comment: Do you want the loop to run indefinitely and forever, or do you also want something like "if user enters 5 then the program should stop"?

Comment: @Makoto it would change with the "conditionals" that I mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've added some changes to the code itself, so please check it out again.

So what I've done, is place both for loops in an infinite while loop.

```
boolean CO = true;
while(true)
{
    for( ; ;) {
        System.out.print("Enter an ID # (0-9): ");
        int IDinput = input.nextInt();

        if( IDinput <10 && IDinput > 0)
            break;

        System.out.println("The ID entered is incorrect. Please enter the correct ID  \n");
    }
    for( ; ; ) {
        System.out.println("\n Main Menu " + "\n 1: check balance " + " \n 2: withdraw" + "\n 3: deposit" + "\n 4: go back to ID" + "\n 5: terminate program");
        System.out.print(" Enter a choice: ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        if(choice == 1) {
            System.out.print("\n The balance is " + test.getBalance());
            continue;
        }
        else if(choice == 2) {
            System.out.print("How much would you like to withdraw: ");
            double withdraw = input.nextDouble();
            test.withdraw(withdraw);
            continue;
        }
        else if(choice == 3) {
            System.out.print("How much would you like to deposit: ");
            double deposit = input.nextDouble();
            test.deposit(deposit);
            continue;
        }
        else if( choice == 4)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(choice == 5)
        {
            CO = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(CO == true)
    {
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

According to the code you posted, the program keeps running forever, so read the comments in the code. I've taken the liberty of giving another choice to the user, to enter 5 if he wants to stop the program.

`CO` stands for "Continue Outer".

By default, `CO` remains true. So when the user enters 4, then the second loop breaks. Since `CO` is still true, the outermost loop continues.

If the user enters 5, then `CO` becomes false, and the second loop breaks.
Now, because `CO` is false, the outermost loop breaks, and the program stops.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ran the code and it worked perfectly. Do you mind explaining the if(CO == true){ CO = false;.... etc. ? (The last bit of code in your post). Thanks!

Comment: very understandable thanks for breaking it down! Excellent answer!